# Why didn't Donna die when she remembered she was part time lord, and couln't the Doctor see her again after she remembered?

Tags: doctor-who

Why didn't Donna die when she remembered she was part time lord, and couldn't the Doctor see her again after she remembered?

Comment: Can you indicate when she remembered.

Answer (score 5):

She never fully remembered; she came close, but triggered a defence mechanism the Doctor placed in her mind:

> **Donna:** [I]t hurts. My head. It keeps getting hotter, and hotter, and hotter, and hotter, and hotter!
>
> *[a wave of gold energy erupts from Donna's head, knocking out a whole bunch of Masters]*
>
> **Donna:** What did I... *[she collapses]*
>
> **Wilf:** *[watching on a monitor]* Donna? What was that? Donna? Donna, are you there? Donna.! Donna! Donna!
>
> **Doctor:** *[The Master removed the Doctor's gag]* That's better. Hello. But really, did you think I'd leave my best friend without a defence mechanism?
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* "The End of Time, Part Two"</sup>

There's no indication that Donna remembers any of this, or anything she almost remembered during this episode. In fact, the very next time we see her, she's none the wiser, and seemingly unaware that she ever left her house (emphasis mine):

> **Shaun:**  We've got to do something. Wake her up. Donna? Can you hear me? Donna?
>
> *[Donna opens her eyes as we hear the TARDIS dematerialize]*
>
> **Shaun:** Donna? It's me. I'm here. You're safe. You're home.
>
> **Donna:** **But I was.** What happened? Did I miss something again?
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* "The End of Time, Part Two"</sup>

Absent other information, it seems as though the Doctor's mental block is still in effect. Since this is Donna's last appearance on the show<sup>1</sup>, presumably she is still unaware of her adventures with the Doctor.

---

<sup>1</sup> Aside from her image being used in "Let's Kill Hitler", and some archive footage in "The Girl Who Died"

Comment: In the show, yes. She has re-appeared in comic form.

Comment: @Richard I don't know much about the comics, but from my research she's only appeared in [one strip](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Meeting_(comic_story)) since "The End of Time", which indicates she still doesn't remember the Doctor

Comment: That's the fella.

Comment: @Richard And let's not forget the [audio adventures](https://www.bigfinish.com/news/v/doctor-who-the-tenth-doctor-adventures)!

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I gather those are set mid-season, rather than later (chronologically speaking). Frankly I'd sooner shove spoons in my ears than listen to one more second of Donna so I'll have to take your word for it.

Comment: @Richard I've now watched the whole of Series 4, and she's still my favourite companion. Sorry. (Unless you count one-offs, in which case Christina de Souza might get a look in ... or that might just be because *Planet of the Dead* is the last episode I watched).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yuk. She's the worst thing to ever happen to Doctor Who. She's not funny, she's not talented and she can't act. Ugh and that voice. I'd sooner listen to the complete [Ring Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen) scored for nails and chalkboards.

Comment: @Valorum I always considered the number of times they brought back Rose & Martha during Donna's tenure that even the _writers_ weren't particularly fond of her. Maybe that's just my head canon.

Comment: @FreeMan - She was famously disliked by the writing team

Comment: (glad to know I'm not the only one)